# Detect repetitive patterns in a text file and create a fingerprint of this patterns for future recognition

Tags: python, templates, pattern-matching

Given a file, loaded by a user, i.e:

```
# This is a comment
# Another one
nameserver 1.2.3.4
nameserver 5.5.6.7
nameserver 8.9.10.11
# A third one
nameserver 12.13.14.15
nameserver 16.17.18.19
```

I would like to find a way, to detect repetitive patterns, lines, blocks,...
The idea, is to be able to generate 2 things:

1. A file-type signature, in order to be able to immediately recognise files looking alike
2. A file template, for similar files creation from dynamic values

I am still trying to figure out how I could detect that this example file, has:

- Lines which always start by a "#"
- Blocks of repetitive lines always starting by "nameserver" and followed by a space and a variable string

SHall I try to use re.compile on every possible line and then word, and then build a "map" of what is similar etc, or there are tools I could leverage instead?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for something like [W-Shingling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-shingling). Basically, for each file you create a set of contiguous subsequences of words and calculate their checksums, then you use these checksums to measure similarity of documents.

Simple search gives [a python implementation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shingling/0.1).

Comment: Hey, thank you. I didn't know how to formulate my searches. I am not english and sometimes it is hard to find what I am looking for.